# Hosting a standalone .Net Core Web Application

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-core, .net-core

We've created a .Net Core Web Application and are deploying it as a stand-alone exe. The main reason for deploying it stand-alone was to not be dependent upon the version of .Net Core installed on the target Windows server. We'll be creating many instances of these environments.

This Web App will act as a service for a client Web App; it's critical for the service App to be up.

The question I have is: Apart from calling Process.Start() from the dependent Web App and perhaps monitoring its health is there a more appropriate way to host this exe?

Comment: "Apart from calling Process.Start() from the dependant Web App" this seems super bad. why would you do this?

Comment: Is this intended to work only on the same machine where it will be accesed from (e.g. from 172.0.0.1)? Or, alternatively, it should work as a server for multiple machines?

Comment: @Ewan thanks for the cautionary word.

Comment: @Theraot the Service App will probably need to be accessible from multiple machines in the future, but not immediately.

Comment: I have to believe that this isn't the problem it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

The following makes sense: and application that launches an standalone web server alongside to a browser pointing to it. Then the application can hide, perhaps placing an icon in notification area to allow to stop the server. The application may also monitor the server for crashes, backing up logs and restarting the server if needed.

And yes, that same thing will work if you want to access the server from another machine. However, I will throw to you some extra requirements:

- Have it start with the machine. You probably can do it by a script on start or registry configuration.
- Ease deploying new versions. I suggest blue-green deployment (look it up).
- Monitor the activity of the server

Ah activity... you know what? if the server deal with concurrent requests from different clients on different threads, it does not make sense to put all logs in a single file. If you do, you would be introducing synchronization among the threads to access the file, and that will slow it down. So, have a log per thread... which also brings me to: pool your threads. Futhermore, capture exceptions at request level. A broken request should not bring down the server.

Now, your server could open logs files sharing the right to read them, and then to monitor the activity you can open them for read and take statistics of reported exceptions and requests served.

---

Finally, I would vow for developing a service. I am assuming we are talking of Windows. Instead of doing all that work in the application that monitors the server, have a service monitor the server, then the application just issues commands to the service. You can use an `EvenLog` to send the monitor data.

Now, a crash in the application is no problem. There is tie between monitoring the server and any UI. In fact, you can have simple command line application to issue commands to the service, which are useful if you want to write scripts to automate tasks (for example to run from scheduled tasks). If you think that is not useful, ask an IT Admin near you.

---

Oh, one more thing. Your server can be the service. It can register itself as service, then start itself, and on entry it can check if it is running as service or not. However, that could make blue-green deployment harder, so plan it ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, a Windows Service looks appropriate here. And .Net Core supports running under it with a Nuget extension.

Here's a how to article: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/09/12/hosting-an-asp-net-core-web-application-as-a-windows-service/.

Comment: A Windows Service is what I meant at the second half of my answer. I suppose I could have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a long way to go?

If you use windows systems you can create a self-contained deployment on IIS this will make the service independet of .NET installations

Publishing your app as self-contained produces an application that includes the .NET runtime and libraries, and your application and its dependencies. Users of the application can run it on a machine that doesn't have the .NET runtime installed.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Please note this applie to NET 6 or NET 7 not apps build upon the full NET Framework

hth /Peter

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/254820)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).